# Does not get selected value from 1st option just after page load

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have following select option:

```
<select id='media' name='media'>
   <option value='1'>media1</option>
   <option value='2'>media2</option>
   <option value='3'>media3</option>
</select>
```

And following jquery code to display selected value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#media").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Problem is after first time page load if I select Media1, it does not show anything. If I select media2 or media3 then it is showing their value correctly. Even If I select media1 after selecting media2 or media3, then value of media1 is showing as usual. Perhaps this due to the reason that at page load media1 is the first option which is by default selected and when I select the same media1 option at first, value of select option remains same (media1).

How to resolve this? i,e. even I select first option at first it's value will be showed.

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event fires (rather obviously) when the value of the `select` is changed. If the value on load of the page is `1`, selecting that again will not raise the event.

If you do not want this behaviour you would need to add another option which would be the default on load. Something like this:

```
<select id='media' name='media'>
   <option value=''>Please select...</option>
   <option value='1'>media1</option>
   <option value='2'>media2</option>
   <option value='3'>media3</option>
</select>
```

The side effect of this being that you would then need to validate that a valid selection had been made.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#media").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        if (id != '') {
            alert(id);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I dont want to add blank value and also want to get response by selecting first option. Isn't there any event handler or any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably like to use keyup. You should use an alternate method of informing the user since using alerts is not pretty. I would like to note that you don't do anything with your dataString in your code. Did you mean to use that in the alert?

Use either `$("#media").keyup(function() {...});`.

You may need to combine this with your change logic. Just make sure not to use an alternate alert method. Your code might look something like this:

```
var dataString = '';
var media = $("#media");
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //page has loaded
    dataString = getAlertValue(this);
    media.change(function()
    {
       dataString = getAlertValue(this);
       alert(id);
       return false;
    });

    media.click(function()
    {
       dataString = getAlertValue(this);
       alternateAlertMethod(id);
       return false;
    });
});

function getAlertValue(element){
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
    return dataString;
}

function alternateAlertMethod(id){
    console.log(id);
}
```

Also, having a dummy option that tells the user to select an option is probably a good route to take.

Comment: Actually I don't want to alert the value. I want to collect the selected option value and after that fetching data by post or get data based on selected option. But problem is that when user select first option, no value is returning and thus no data is fetching by the jquery get or post method.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have are using a default option, so the user isn't actually selecting anything. You will have to fetch that data regardless of whether something is clicked OR have a default option that instructs the user to select a different option.

If you use keyup like this `$("#media").keyup(function() {});` you won't get the problem of alerting the user until after they select. Tested on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

add the attribute:

```
autocomplete = "off"
```

to your form (or select) element avoiding data memorization in browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the change event on page load for the select box.This way as soon as say first item gets populated in select box it will fire the event.

Ex: $("#select").trigger('change');